# Count number of visible rows with criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

In the beginning I used this formula `SUBTOTAL(3;(A14:A150>0))` and it works perfectly  but now I need to add a condition that I must count the number of rows where the value in the column F is greater than 0.

This formula `COUNTIF(F14:F150;">0")` return the right result, but when I filter  I don’t have the right one.

I tried also `SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3;F14:F150)/A1*(F14:F150>0))` it return the same thing as the COUNTIF.

Comment: The third formula divides by A1 - just out of curiosity, can you say what that was for because it isn't mentioned anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another column with formula:

```
=IF(SUBTOTAL(103;F14))
```

Because you are using filters this formula will help you determine if your cell is hidden or not.
Now you can use, assuming that latter formula is in column `G`:

```
=COUNTIFS(F14:F150;">0";G14:G150;">0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Array-entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F14:F150>0),IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(F14:F150,ROW(F14:F150)-MIN(ROW(F14:F150)),,1)),F14:F150,""))/A1
```

Comment: It's really neat but I don't get what the /A1 is for?

Comment: It was in the original formula.

Comment: Yes...but OP didn't define what was in A1. Oh well.

Comment: A1 => =(SUBTOTAL(3;A14:A1048576))
but i have this error
the formula you typed contains an error

Comment: If you use semicolons, replace all the commas in mine with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get exactly your needs but you may want to use

```
=SUMIFS(F14:F150,F14:F150,">0",A14:A150,">0")
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(F14:F150,">0",A14:A150,">0")
```

Comment: i have this error the formula you typed contains an error